# AWS generate_presigned_url mp4 playback getting stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, mp4

I'm having an issue regarding generate_presigned_url from boto3. I'm perfectly able to generate a resigned URL for an mp4 object in my s3. But I'm having an issue that if a user is jumping around a lot with the playback of the video the video will get stuck and become unplayable. This happens both if I try to use a video player and if I try to access it directly through the video link (See gif).

https://media.giphy.com/media/v1.Y2lkPTc5MGI3NjExNTM3OTk4NmFmZDNkZmNjNjIyNmUwZTQ5NDMyMWJkNWQ2MTVmODIyMiZjdD1n/vDwTFAnMZViPW8mQyp/giphy.gif

Python code for generating the object:

```
def get_videos(video_path):
s3_client = client('s3')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='_Bucket', Prefix=video_path)

return [
    {
        "key": content.get('Key'),
        "url": s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': '_Bucket', 'Key': content.get('Key')}, ExpiresIn=3600)
    } for content in response.get('Contents', [])
]
```

Comment: What happens if you make the MP4 public and use a regular S3 URL (no a pre-signed URL)? Same issue? If so, that suggests it's not related to the pre-signed URL.

Comment: Tested it and the problem still exists, the weird thing is that when playing back the video locally it doesn't have any issues. Is this a common problem with s3?

Comment: Well there's a big difference between playing a local MP4 and one fetched piecemeal from a remote server. If the video player freezes, that sounds like a bug in the video player tbh.

Comment: Are you using a browser to play the video?  What does it show in the network traffic?

Comment: Yes, the video is accessed directly in the browser. The network traffic shows that as soon as the video gets stuck no more packets are received or being sent